# bash. How to pick random line from a variable containing numerous lines?

Tags: bash, variables, shuffle

```
a=$(find ./ -name "*-*.txt")
```

Now I need to get random line from **$a**, but **shuf** yelling at me

```
b=$(shuf -n1 $a)
```

**shuf: extra operand**

What's my issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `shuf` takes a single filename argument, and shuffles the contents of that file. You want it to shuffle its arguments instead; for that, use `shuf -e`:

```
b=$(shuf -e -n1 $a)
```

BTW, there's a subtler problem with this: it'll get confused by filenames with spaces and/or wildcard characters. Maybe not going to happen in your environment, but I prefer to use scripting idioms that don't fall over due to funny filenames. To protect against that, store the filenames in an array rather than counting on word splitting to tell where one stops and the next begins:

```
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(find ./ -name "*-*.txt" -print0)
b=$(shuf -en1 "${arr[@]}")
```

If you don't need to store the file list, things are even simpler:

```
b=$(find ./ -name "*-*.txt" -print0 | shuf -zn1 | tr -d '\0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$RANDOM](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) for this.

Notes:

- `${#array[@]}` gives the size of the array
- `$((min + RANDOM % max))` gives you a random integer, whereas `max` is not included.
- You can access an array item at index `index_number` like so `${array[index_number]}`

```sh
# define array
a=()
while read line
do
    # read the file list line by line and add to the array
    a+=("$line")
done < <(find ./files -name '*-*.txt')

random_index=$((0 + RANDOM % ${#a[@]}))

echo ${a[$random_index]}
```

Comment: I took **random_index=$((0 + RANDOM % ${#a[@]}))** and then **echo $random_index** returns 0 always

Comment: `a=$(find ...)` creates a simple string variable, not an array. To store the file list as an array, use `readarray -d '' -t a < <(find ./ -name "*-*.txt" -print0)`.